# Killing user session (logout) forcefully in jboss portal server

Tags: jboss-portal

I want to kill user session forcefully (logout a user), in case of an activity like Change password. How can i do this pragmatically in jboss portal server.

When this activity happens my portlet's processAction method is called and I have RenderRequest available but not HTTPRequest, so session.invalidate is not an option i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the approach documented in the following JBoss article:

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionInvalidate